# Is there a shortcut to paste value in the search line in nano?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text, editor, nano

What I'm trying to do:

- copy some text value
- open log file with nano
- press Ctrl+W (for search)
- here I would like to press some shortcut to paste the text value in the search line (coz it annoys to right click, then paste every time)
  [image]

Comment: Have you already tryed Ctrl+U or F10 ?

Comment: @Overflow 404 yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When using PuTTy (or SuperPutty), in Windows, selecting/copying the text and right-click on it should work.